# Find index of any one of a set of search values in an array (KQL)

Tags: arrays, kql

I'm using [`array_index_of`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arrayindexoffunction) in [KQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/) to find the index of a value in an array, then pass the result to another function, i.e.:

```
array_index_of(arr, "foo")
```

How can I find the first index of any value from a set of search values easily? I know I could do this using a combination of [`iif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/iiffunction) and two calls to `array_index_of` for each search value, e.g., searching for three values:

```
iif(array_index_of(arr, "foo") <> -1, array_index_of(arr, "foo"), iif(array_index_of(arr, "bar") <> -1, array_index_of(arr, "foo"), array_index_of(arr, "baz")))
```

But this is of course quite verbose and cumbersome, and breaks DRY. Is there a cleaner and more concise way of doing this, perhaps with other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that's shorter and easier to read/maintain:

```
let MyArray = dynamic(["Hello", "world", "some", "other", "word", "fox"]);
print max_of(
    array_index_of(MyArray, "foo"),
    array_index_of(MyArray, "bar"),
    array_index_of(MyArray, "baz"))
```

But depending on your data, this method can be less or more efficient than the one you proposed (because this method calls `array_index_of` for all elements even if the first one was found, while yours calls `array_index_of` only until an existing element is reached, but for that one the function is called twice).

Currently there is no better way to do what you want. If you want, you can suggest a new function (`array_index_of_any`?) on https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice - its implementation will obviously allow the best performance as well as better readability.

Comment: OK, great. I like your solution as readability is more important here. The performance impact is minimal. I've added a [new idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer/suggestions/42663010-add-kql-function-to-get-first-index-in-an-array) on the feedback forum.